# core data saving in textboxes in table view controller

Tags: uitableview, core-data

I have created a five column (text boxes) cell (row) in table view controller with an option of add button. When a user clicks on add button, a new row (cell) with five column (text boxe) is added in a table view controller with null values. I want that when user fills the text boxes the data should get saved in database or if he changes any data in previous text boxes also it get saved.

this is my save btn coding..

```
- (IBAction)btn_save:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger noOfRow=[(NSSet *)[projectObject valueForKey:@"rs_project_Input"] count];
    NSLog(@"Save Btn: No of rows for saving %d",noOfRow);
    for (row1=0; row1<noOfRow; row1++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Row is %d",row1);

        path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row1 inSection:0];

        Input_Details *inputDetailsObject1=[[self sortInputs] objectAtIndex:path.row];
        /*
          Update the input details from the values in the text fields.
        */
        EditingTableViewCell *cell;

        cell = (EditingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row1 inSection:0]];
        inputDetailsObject1.mh_Up= cell.cell_MH_up.text;
        inputDetailsObject1.mh_down=cell.textField.text;
        NSLog(@"Saving the MH_up value %@ is saved in save at index path %d",inputDetailsObject1.mh_Up,row1);

        [masterController saveContext];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

My problem is that the code is not helping in saving the data. Plz help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use the table view cells as a data source, which will not work (apart from being a bad design). The problem is that

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row1 inSection:0]]
```

returns `nil` if the cell at that row is currently not visible. (A table view allocates only cells for the visible rows and reuses these cells as you scroll up or down.)

You have to track changes to the text fields immediately, e.g. by implementing a `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate function, and store the changed text in your data source.

Comment: Thanks Martin..This helped me..actually this is the first core data project i am trying so, i was very confused. textFieldDidEndEditing: did magic.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry to trouble u again, but this raised another problem.  I can easily move my cursor from one cell text box to another cell text box to feed values. However i am unable to move my cursor from one text box to another text box of same cell to feed values. please help

Comment: @user1489709: I have reverted that changes, because you have completely changed the contents of your question after you got an accepted answer. Your should start a new question if you have new problems.

Comment: sorry martin...i am using this for the first time so didnt knew that we cannot change the contents...

Comment: I have posted new question at this post if you could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263517/trying-to-save-data-in-core-data-from-uitableviewcontroller-textbox?rq=1